# Manifoldjs: <Object> has no method 'parse' on windows

Tags: manifoldjs

when trying to use

```
manifoldjs http://www.fox-poker.com
```

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\manifoldjs\node_modules\q\q.js:155
>                   throw e;
>                         ^ TypeError: Object # has no method 'parse'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have an up-to-date version of Node installed on your machine, also make sure your ManifoldJS version is up to date.

If you still have trouble, you can generate the same that the Node tool outputs via the website at http://manifoldjs.com/